# How to make php variables inside double quotes appear bold in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

In notepad++ when I type:

```
echo "This is a string with a $my_variable";
```

It makes `$my_variable` bold font so it stands out. And it only does this within double quotes.

How can I replicate this functionality in Sublime? Please note I do not want php variables to appear in bold font throughout the file, only those that are within double quotes.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [Sublime forum](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/)?

Comment: @MaciejLach why? It's on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit your color scheme's `.tmTheme` file to enable this. To find its path, select **`Preferences -> Settings-User`** and check the value of the `"color_scheme"` key. If it's not present, you're using `Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme`.

Next you need to open the file. In ST2 this is straightforward, just select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open your `Packages` folder in your operating system's file manager (Windows Explorer, Finder, Nautilus, etc.), browse to the correct folder, find the `.tmTheme` file, and open it in Sublime with XML syntax. In ST3, by default packages are stored in `.sublime-package` zip files, so you'll need to install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin from Package Control to easily access them. Once installed, open the Command Palette, type ***`prv`***, then choose `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`. Scroll down to the correct directory, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, find the correct file, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. Change the syntax to XML if you want syntax highlighting.

Now that we have the `.tmTheme` file open, you'll need to add a new entry. Scroll down to the very bottom, and put a new line above the `</array>` tag and below the final `</dict>` tag. You can now insert the following block:

```xml
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>PHP Variable in Double-Quoted String</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>string.quoted.double.php variable</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>fontStyle</key>
                <string>bold</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

Save the file, and you should be just about ready to go. First, close Sublime, and if you're using ST2 you should go into the folder where your `.tmTheme` file resides and delete any `.tmTheme.cache` and `.tmTheme.chback` files with the same name as your `.tmTheme` file. Restart Sublime, and the changes *should* take effect.

Comment: Thanks. I had to make it "string.quoted.double.php variable.other.php" for it to work though.